# Select values in a SELECT based on a JSON with angularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, laravel

I have a `<select>` tag with fixed values like:

```
<select ng-model="users" multiple>
    <options value="1" name="Foo">
    <options value="2" name="Alex">
    <options value="3" name="Bar">
    <options value="4" name="John">
    ...
 </select>
```

and a JSON array from Laravel's Eloquent ORM like:

```
 [ { id: 2, name: "Alex"} ,
   { id: 5, name: "Bob"} ]
```

Providing that I cannot easily use `ng-selected` on the `<option>s` how do I select the values according to the id field of the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `ng-selected`. Set `users` model in controller like

```
$scope.users = ["1","3"];
```

And `HTML`

```
<select ng-model="users" multiple>
    <option value="1">Foo</option>
    <option value="2">Alex</option>
    <option value="3">Bar</option>
    <option value="4">John</option>
    <option value="5">Bob</option>
</select>
```

`Foo` and `Bar` will be selected.
[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dPykqaVLAr9kMj7DNGU2?p=preview)